# Shapefile not showing in proper location

Tags: qgis, shapefile

Working in QGIS 3.0.1; I just switched to QGIS and am trying to get used to it.

I have a shapefile from SW Maps app of a track walked on hiking trails, and am attempting to make a basic map using this and a topo quadrangle for the area. However, while both are in same CRS (WGS84), the shapefile shows up in a completely different area. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you enabled `on the fly reprojection`? Why are you using 3.0 instead of the latest LTR 3.4?

Comment: what is **'SW'** supposed to mean ?

Comment: Using 3.0 because I am on my field laptop and dont have permissions to change any programs it is inconvenient but gotta use what i got.

Comment: "SW Maps". It is phone app that I use in leui of gps at times

Comment: Sounds like the CRS is incorrectly defined for one of the layers (or both). A common confusion is that the term WGS84 is often used interchangably with the unprojected CRS using the WGS84 ellipsoid. Maybe one of your layers should be in a projected CRS using the WGS84 ellipsoid. You'll need to figure out what CRS each layer should be in, and re-define that layer's CRS (in layer properties). Look at the metadata for the topo quad, and read the export settings and documentation for the SW Maps app.

Comment: You didn't switch coordinates ? What do u call 'completely different area' ?

Comment: Check coordinate systems of both layers and let us know about the EPSG code. For example, "common" coordinates provided by the GPS system are in WGS84 EPSG:4326. Same for the coordinates which gives you Google Maps.

Comment: Try to find sample coordinates of all layers (may need to add them to separate QGIS sessions) and edit your question to include the values. That will help us identify the coordinate reference systems.

Answer (score 3):

**It sounds like the CRS is incorrectly defined for one of the layers (or both).**

Add a basemap from the QuickMapServices plugin. Compare both of your layers to the basemap. See if either of your layers is in the correct location or not. Focus on correcting the CRS of whichever layer displays in the wrong location compared to the QMS basemap.

You'll need to figure out what CRS each layer *should* be in. Look at the metadata for the topo quad, and read the export settings and documentation for the SW Maps app. Once you figure out what CRS that layer should be in, re-define that layer's CRS (in the layer properties).

---

Note: I think this is the best answer *currently* possible based on the information you've provided *so far*. If you check on the metadata (as mentioned above) and update your question with the information you find, I'll try provide a more specific solution.